# Capitalization of "paragraph"

Tags: capitalization

When referencing a specific paragraph, should the word "paragraph" be capitalized?

For example:

"Read Paragraph 1"

or

"Read paragraph 1"

Thanks!

Comment: Its a style issue. Lower case is preferred in style guides on both sides of the pond, but I'm not sure about other English-speaking countries.

Answer (score 1):

Both can be correct. You'll see examples using both formats if you Google `"see paragraph" filetype:pdf`. In more formal writing I suggest referring to the paragraphs as proper nouns with capital letters.

Comment: It doesn't have to do with formality, but with the particular style guide in use.

Answer (score 1):

I ran several variations on Google NGrams, and in every single one of them, *Paragraph* with a capitalized *p* came last or negligible compared to the other example. The fact that they still exist, though, means that it is a stylistic choice, though *paragraph* is more common. In addition, according to general rules of punctuation, it would be more correct to use *paragraph*, since the word is not a proper noun, or other such rules listed here: http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/capital.asp. I must digress for a moment to say that it would be much more discretionary if you weren't citing the paragraph in the middle of the sentence; it would *then* be completely your choice. But see below; it's not as discretionary as it appears:

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=read+paragraph%2C+read+Paragraph&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cread%20paragraph%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cread%20Paragraph%3B%2Cc0

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Read+Paragraph%2CRead+paragraph&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CRead%20Paragraph%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CRead%20paragraph%3B%2Cc0

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Read+Paragraph+1%2CRead+paragraph+1%2C+read+paragraph+1%2C+read+Paragraph+1&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CRead%20paragraph%201%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cread%20paragraph%201%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cread%20Paragraph%201%3B%2Cc0

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Read+Paragraph+2%2CRead+paragraph+2%2Cread+paragraph+2%2Cread+Paragraph+2&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CRead%20paragraph%202%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cread%20paragraph%202%3B%2Cc0

You can also use the pilcrow symbol (¶), the section sign (§) in legal terms, possibly abbreviate the paragraph with a *p*, and, most importantly, according to Writing Explained, you can abbreviate *paragraph* as *par.* or *para.*, which both saves time and solves your dilemma. See here: http://writingexplained.org/english-abbreviations/paragraph. If you don't choose these shortenings, however, as a person who reads research papers a lot, I would urge you to go with the lowercase.